# C# Explorer Interface select file

Tags: c#, listview, treeview

So I followed MS article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645.aspx

This is Creating an Explorer Style Interface with the ListView and TreeView Controls Using the Designer.

Right now it loads up a tree view on the left with folders, and then on the rigth it shows the list view.

Now when i select a folder or file on the right hand pane, I would like to get the full file path.  Howerver, when I do the listview.selectIndex[0], it only provides me the name.  I belive this is becuase the path is being dirrived from the left hand tree view.

Does this make sense?  What i want to accomplish is to select the file and it provide me the full path.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I do the listview.selectIndex[0], it only provides me the name. I belive this is becuase the path is being dirrived from the left hand tree view.

Correct. You need to combine the path from the `TreeView` control with the name of the item in the `ListView` control.

Sample code (where `TreeView1` is your left-hand `TreeView` control, and `ListView1` is your right-hand `ListView` control):

```
String GetSelectedItemPath()
{
    String path = String.Empty;

    // See if a node is selected in the TreeView
    TreeNode selectedNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode;
    if (selectedNode != null)
    {
        // Also check that an item is selected in the ListView
        ListViewItem item = ListView1.SelectedItems[0];
        if (item != null)
        {
            // Build the full path to the selected item.
            path = selectedNode.FullPath + TreeView1.PathSeparator + item.Text;
        }
    }

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If on the RIGHT you see the content of the folder selected on the LEFT, I would say, yes, you are right. To get the complete path to the folder selected on the RIGHT pan, you need to concatenate the path of the folder selected on `TreeView` (LEFT) and the `folder name` (RIGHT).